# Two conditions in javascript

Tags: javascript

I want a div (#expand) to appear when window is >=650 as long as another div (.sr) is not displaying (this is, I need two conditions).

I have this working code so far, but I'm not sure how to add the second condition.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(window).resize(function(){
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    if(w >= 650){
        $("#expand").css('display','inline-block');
    }
    else {
        $("#expand").css('display','none');
    }
});

</script>
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`&&`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Logical_AND_()) to add another condition: `&& $(".sr").css("display") == "none"`

```
$(window).resize(function(){
    var w = window.innerWidth;
    if(w >= 650 && $(".sr").css("display") == "none"){  //added code here
        $("#expand").css('display','inline-block');
    }
    else {
        $("#expand").css('display','none');
    }
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Worked... I tried something like that but I must have done it wrong with syntaxis. Have a great day!

Comment: Great! Any chance you could mark it as the corect answer if it helped you? @AndrésNizovoy

Comment: Sure, I'm sorry. New on this!